# Use Raphael to manipulate SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

Is it possible to use Raphael to manipulate an embedded SVG image? I used Raphael in the past to draw shapes, but haven't actually seen it being used to manipulate an existing SVG image. If not, is there anything else that allows me to easily change colours, add events, etc. to polygons of an embedded SVG image?

Answer (score 4):

From my experience reading the `Raphael.js` source, I have to agree with previous posts. The only way I can think of to replace or modify the SVG is by replacing/modifying the markup/DOM itself.

All I want to add in my answer is a short, general explanation of *why* this is so. Raphael is designed as an SVG/VML *generator*. That is, Raphael makes JavaScript objects and appends their corresponding SVG/VML markup to the DOM as they are made. The objects have lots of additional properties that make them work within the Raphael framework.

It may be possible to write a plugin that can construct a Raphael object around an SVG element by reading its properties, but, I suspect that such an object may not have all the information it needs to coexist with the other Raphael objects. Certainly, no such parsing/reconstruction functionality currently exists.

Comment: the Raphael documentation regarding the 'ninja' mode supports your remarks.  the Raphael 'ninja' mode removes the global Raphael object but the documentation indicates that using 'ninja' mode might prevent plugins from working as they need to access the Raphael global obj[link](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.ninja)

Comment: Ninja mode has nothing to do with my answer. I'm not referring to the global Raphael object, but rather, the individual objects that correspond to the SVG elements that are created by Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, yesterday I found the [glitchsvgicons](http://www.dinkypage.com/76566) page doing that.
Although in a very primitive way, just using a regex replace of parts.
It can be hint, though: apparently you can use good old search/replace of text parts on SVG icons. But it is more prone to issues than using a real Dom tree...

Comment: Judging from the lack of replies, I think there isn't any possibility to use Raphael to do this. I think I stick with jquery to manipulate the DOM tree.